# Design decision: should I provide a thread-safety version for all low-level library?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I've experience a really painful java learning curve and still a newbie.

I'm designing a low-level library class, in the future it possibly can be used in an multi-threading environment or just in a single thread. I have no idea of that.

**I can let user of this class to synchronize from outside. But that will be much more inefficient than provide a thread-safety version.**

This is p-code.

```
Class Example{
    public int checkAndProcess(){
        WriteLock writeLock=this.getWriteLock();
        ReadLock readLock=new ReadLock(writeLock);
        int a;
        try{
            lockManager.lock(readLock);
            a=readSomething();
        }finally{
            lockManager.release(readLock);
        }
        if(a!=null){
            return a;
        }
        try{
            lockManager.lock(writeLock);
            a=doSomeProcessing();
        }finally{
            lockManager.release(writeLock);
        }
        return a;
    }
}
```

It will be much faster than synchronize from outside because readlock doesn't block. It's create and garbage-collected in every method call.

Problem:

**Overhead**. WriteLock is pretty complex, ReadLock is cheap and simple but it's created in every method call(and possibly multiple), so still an overhead.

Should I provide a thread-safety version of every such class? Every open source library doesn't do that. But if I don't provide it, let user synchronize from outside, performance will be lowered.

Or is there any better way ?

Edit:

Should I split it?

Split it into a stateless processor and a store, and let user to create readLock/writeLock to lock? If I do that, the store will be totally designed for the processor, doesn't have much meaning for other class, and the library will be quickly boomed by those things.

This is my real code. You can ignore it if you don't like.

```
package lazycatTools.runtime;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;

import org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.jobs.Job;
import org.osgi.framework.AllServiceListener;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;
import org.osgi.framework.Constants;
import org.osgi.framework.InvalidSyntaxException;
import org.osgi.framework.ServiceEvent;
import org.osgi.framework.ServiceListener;
import org.osgi.framework.ServiceReference;

public class DynamicServiceTracker {

    private final HashMap<Long,Object> _serviceCache;
    private final HashMap<String,Long> _keyCache;

    private final MultiResourceSchedulingRule _writeLock;

    private final ServiceListener _tracker;

    private final BundleContext _context;

    public DynamicServiceTracker(BundleContext context){
        Assert.isLegal(context!=null);
        _serviceCache=new HashMap<Long,Object>();
        _keyCache=new HashMap<String,Long>();
        HashSet<Object> lockResource=new HashSet<Object>(4);
        lockResource.add(_serviceCache);
        lockResource.add(_keyCache);
        _writeLock=new MultiResourceSchedulingRule<DynamicServiceTracker,Object>(this,lockResource);
        _context=context;
        _tracker=new AllServiceListener(){

            @Override
            public void serviceChanged(ServiceEvent event) {
                if(event.getType()==ServiceEvent.UNREGISTERING){
                    ServiceReference<?> ref=event.getServiceReference();
                    Long sid=(Long)ref.getProperty(Constants.SERVICE_ID);
                    String[] classes=(String[])ref.getProperty(Constants.OBJECTCLASS);
                    boolean ungetService=false;
                    try{
                        Job.getJobManager().beginRule(_writeLock, null);
                        for(String clazz : classes){
                            if(_keyCache.get(clazz)==sid){
                                _keyCache.remove(clazz);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if(_serviceCache.containsKey(sid)){
                            _serviceCache.remove(sid);
                            ungetService=true;
                        }
                    }finally{
                        Job.getJobManager().endRule(_writeLock);
                    }
                    if(ungetService){
                        //The order of ungetting a serviceReference is not important
                        _context.ungetService(ref);
                    }
                    SharedSchedulingRule readLock=new SharedSchedulingRule(_writeLock);
                    try{
                        Job.getJobManager().beginRule(readLock, null);
                        if(_serviceCache.size()==0){
                            _context.removeServiceListener(_tracker);
                        }
                    }finally{
                        Job.getJobManager().endRule(readLock);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }

    public Object getService(String clazz) throws Exception{
        Object cachedService=null;
        Long key;
        SharedSchedulingRule readLock=new SharedSchedulingRule(_writeLock);
        try{
            Job.getJobManager().beginRule(readLock, null);
            key=_keyCache.get(clazz);
            if(key!=null){
                cachedService=_serviceCache.get(key);
            }
        }finally{
            Job.getJobManager().endRule(readLock);
        }
        if(cachedService!=null){
            return cachedService;
        }
        ServiceReference<?> ref=_context.getServiceReference(clazz);
        Long sid=(Long)ref.getProperty(Constants.SERVICE_ID);
        Object newService=_context.getService(ref);
        try{
            Job.getJobManager().beginRule(_writeLock, null);
            key=_keyCache.get(clazz);
            if(key!=null){
                cachedService=_serviceCache.get(key);
            }else{
                _keyCache.put(clazz,sid);
                _serviceCache.put(sid, newService);
            }
        }finally{
            Job.getJobManager().endRule(_writeLock);
        }

        if(cachedService!=null){
            _context.ungetService(ref);
            return cachedService;
        }else{
            _context.addServiceListener(_tracker);
            return newService;
        }
    }

    public <Type> Type getService(Class<Type> clazz){
        Object cachedService=null;
        Long key;
        SharedSchedulingRule readLock=new SharedSchedulingRule(_writeLock);
        try{
            Job.getJobManager().beginRule(readLock, null);
            key=_keyCache.get(clazz);
            if(key!=null){
                cachedService=_serviceCache.get(key);
            }
        }finally{
            Job.getJobManager().endRule(readLock);
        }
        if(cachedService!=null){
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            Type castedService=(Type)cachedService;
            return castedService;
        }
        ServiceReference<Type> ref=_context.getServiceReference(clazz);
        Long sid=(Long)ref.getProperty(Constants.SERVICE_ID);
        Type newService=_context.getService(ref);
        try{
            Job.getJobManager().beginRule(_writeLock, null);
            key=_keyCache.get(clazz);
            if(key!=null){
                cachedService=_serviceCache.get(key);
            }else{
                _keyCache.put(clazz.getName(),sid);
                _serviceCache.put(sid, newService);
            }
        }finally{
            Job.getJobManager().endRule(_writeLock);
        }
        if(cachedService!=null){
            _context.ungetService(ref);
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            Type castedService=(Type)cachedService;
            return castedService;
        }else{
            _context.addServiceListener(_tracker);
            return newService;
        }
    }

    public Object[] getServices(String clazz,String filter) throws InvalidSyntaxException{
        ServiceReference<?>[] refs=_context.getServiceReferences(clazz,filter);
        if(refs==null){
            return null;
        }
        Object[] services=new Object[refs.length];
        int count=refs.length;
        boolean[] serviceAbsence=new boolean[refs.length];
        Long[] SIDs=new Long[refs.length];
        for(int i=0;i<=count-1;i++){
            ServiceReference<?> ref=refs[i];
            SIDs[i]=(Long)ref.getProperty(Constants.SERVICE_ID);
        }
        boolean loop=true;
        SharedSchedulingRule readLock=new SharedSchedulingRule(_writeLock);
        while(loop){
            try{
                Job.getJobManager().beginRule(readLock, null);
                for(int i=0;i<=count-1;i++){
                    if(_serviceCache.containsKey(SIDs[i])==false){
                        serviceAbsence[i]=true;
                    }
                }
            }finally{
                Job.getJobManager().endRule(readLock);
            }
            for(int i=0;i<=count-1;i++){
                if(serviceAbsence[i]==true){
                    services[i]=_context.getService(refs[i]);
                }
            }
            try{
                Job.getJobManager().beginRule(_writeLock, null);
                boolean gotNewRequire=false;
                for(int i=0;i<=count-1;i++){
                    if(_serviceCache.containsKey(SIDs[i])==false && services[i]==null){
                        serviceAbsence[i]=true;
                        gotNewRequire=true;
                    }
                }
                if(gotNewRequire==false){
                    for(int i=0;i<=count-1;i++){
                        Object service=services[i];
                        if(service!=null){
                            _serviceCache.put(SIDs[i], service);
                        }else{
                            services[i]=_serviceCache.get(SIDs[i]);
                        }
                    }
                    loop=false;
                }
            }finally{
                Job.getJobManager().endRule(_writeLock);
            }
        }
        _context.addServiceListener(_tracker);
        return services;    
    }
    public <Type> Collection<Type> getServices(Class<Type> clazz,String filter) throws InvalidSyntaxException{
        Collection<ServiceReference<Type>> refsCollection=_context.getServiceReferences(clazz,filter);
        HashMap<Integer,Type> services=new HashMap<Integer,Type>(refsCollection.size()+1,1.0f);
        if(refsCollection.size()==0){
            return services.values();
        }
        ArrayList<ServiceReference<Type>> refs=new ArrayList<ServiceReference<Type>>(refsCollection);
        int count=refs.size();
        boolean[] serviceAbsence=new boolean[refs.size()];
        Long[] SIDs=new Long[refs.size()];
        for(int i=0;i<=count-1;i++){
            ServiceReference<Type> ref=refs.get(i);
            SIDs[i]=(Long)ref.getProperty(Constants.SERVICE_ID);
        }
        boolean loop=true;
        SharedSchedulingRule readLock=new SharedSchedulingRule(_writeLock);
        while(loop){
            try{
                Job.getJobManager().beginRule(readLock, null);
                for(int i=0;i<=count-1;i++){
                    if(_serviceCache.containsKey(SIDs[i])==false){
                        serviceAbsence[i]=true;
                    }
                }
            }finally{
                Job.getJobManager().endRule(readLock);
            }
            for(int i=0;i<=count-1;i++){
                if(serviceAbsence[i]==true){
                    services.put(i, _context.getService(refs.get(i)));
                }
            }
            try{
                Job.getJobManager().beginRule(_writeLock, null);
                boolean gotNewRequire=false;
                for(int i=0;i<=count-1;i++){
                    if(_serviceCache.containsKey(SIDs[i])==false && services.containsKey(i)==false){
                        serviceAbsence[i]=true;
                        gotNewRequire=true;
                    }
                }
                if(gotNewRequire==false){
                    for(int i=0;i<=count-1;i++){
                        Object service=services.get(i);
                        if(service!=null){
                            _serviceCache.put(SIDs[i], service);
                        }else{
                            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                            Type cachedService=(Type)_serviceCache.get(SIDs[i]);
                            services.put(i,cachedService);
                        }
                    }
                    loop=false;
                }
            }finally{
                Job.getJobManager().endRule(_writeLock);
            }
        }
        _context.addServiceListener(_tracker);
        return services.values();   
    }

}
```

This is MultiResourceSchedulingRule.

```
package lazycatTools.runtime;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;

import org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.jobs.ISchedulingRule;

public class MultiResourceSchedulingRule<ParentType,ResourceType> extends ResourceBindingSchedulingRule<ParentType> implements IMultiResourceSchedulingRule<ParentType,ResourceType>  {

    private final Set<ResourceType> _resources;

    public MultiResourceSchedulingRule(ParentType parent){
        this(parent,new HashSet<ResourceType>());
    }
    public MultiResourceSchedulingRule(ParentType parent,Set<ResourceType> resources){
        super(parent);
        Assert.isLegal(resources!=null);
        _resources=resources;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isConflicting(ISchedulingRule rule){
        if(rule==this){
            return true;
        }
        if(rule instanceof IResourceBindingSchedulingRule<?>){
            final IResourceBindingSchedulingRule<?> casted=(IResourceBindingSchedulingRule<?>)rule;
            if(_resources.contains(casted.getResource())){
                return true;
            }
        }
        if(rule instanceof IMultiResourceSchedulingRule<?,?>){
            final IMultiResourceSchedulingRule<?,?> casted=(IMultiResourceSchedulingRule<?,?>)rule;
            if(Collections.disjoint(_resources,casted.getResources())==false){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean contains(ISchedulingRule rule){
        if(rule==this){
            return true;
        }
        if(rule instanceof IResourceBindingSchedulingRule<?>){
            final IResourceBindingSchedulingRule<?> casted=(IResourceBindingSchedulingRule<?>)rule;
            if(_resources.contains(casted.getResource())){
                return true;
            }
        }
        if(rule instanceof IMultiResourceSchedulingRule){
            final IMultiResourceSchedulingRule<?,?> casted=(IMultiResourceSchedulingRule<?,?>)rule;
            if(_resources.containsAll(casted.getResources())){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public Set<ResourceType> getResources() {
        return Collections.<ResourceType>unmodifiableSet(_resources);
    }   
}
```

And ResourceBindingSchedulingRule.

```
package lazycatTools.runtime;

import org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.jobs.ISchedulingRule;

public class ResourceBindingSchedulingRule<ResourceType> implements IResourceBindingSchedulingRule<ResourceType> {

    private final ResourceType _resource;

    public ResourceBindingSchedulingRule(ResourceType resource){
        Assert.isLegal(resource!=null);
        _resource=resource;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see lazycatTools.runtime.IResourceBindingSchedulingRule#getResource()
     */
    @Override
    public ResourceType getResource() {
        return _resource;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(ISchedulingRule rule) {
        return isConflicting(rule);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isConflicting(ISchedulingRule rule) {
        if(rule==this){
            return true;
        }
        if(rule instanceof IResourceBindingSchedulingRule<?>){
            final IResourceBindingSchedulingRule<?> casted=(IResourceBindingSchedulingRule<?>)rule;
            return _resource==casted.getResource();
        }
        return false;
    }


}
```

SharedSchedulingRule which is used as the readLock in the example.

```
package lazycatTools.runtime;

import org.eclipse.core.runtime.jobs.ISchedulingRule;

public class SharedSchedulingRule implements ISchedulingRule {

    private final ISchedulingRule _rule;

    public SharedSchedulingRule(ISchedulingRule rule){
        _rule=rule;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(ISchedulingRule rule) {
        if(rule==this){
            return true;
        }
        return _rule.contains(rule);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isConflicting(ISchedulingRule rule) {
        if(rule==this){
            return true;
        }
        return _rule.isConflicting(rule);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best option is to make everything **immutable**. Then you don't need to worry about anything :-)

Assuming this isn't possible, then I would recommend **not** making your library thread-safe.

- Thread safety will usually add **overhead**. In a low level library, you shouldn't force users to pay a performance penalty for safety that they might not need.
- Even if you add thread safety at the level of your library, users will *still* probably have to add their own **locking at a higher level** (this is because locks don't compose). So you probably aren't actually saving your users any work.
- You can always add a **synchronised wrapper** later if needed. But you can't remove synchronisation if it is baked in.
- It will make your own library code **simpler**. You can focus on better features rather than worrying about locks.

There are good examples in the Java standard library that follow this approach and logic - e.g. `ArrayList` is not thread safe.

Answer (score 2):

Understand your users. If you aren't able to determine ahead of time or aren't able to make an educated guess on the subject, don't do it.

After the library has been released, listen to your users and they'll let you know.

Answer (score 0):

It simply depends on what kind of users  you have and the way they will use your api. There is no "always right" answer.

If you do decide to go with synchronizing look at using [ReentrantReadWriteLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html) instead of the way you did it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what uses your program will be applied to, but you'd better not make your code too complex before nessary changes. Optimization for multi-threading could be added later, but   after the maturity of your program.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to make it thread-safe, but much more efficient, possibly just one volatile read in common cases. You can provide a more realistic version of your problem so we can understand better.

Comment: I'm programming in eclipse RCP. It's not self-contained.
Data is in two HashMap all variable in the class is final

Comment: I think in your case simply `synchronized` would be faster. You can benchmark to see the difference. read locks are good for overlapping readers. but your reads are so short, overlapping is unlikely.

Comment: java synchronization system can cause deadlock. using eclipse job framework, with well implemented contains method, theoretically there's no deadlock.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with all of the prior answers. It could mean premature optimization to try to figure out the concurrent usage patterns. Best to just not provide support for multithreading and push that onto the users of the library. Sort of like JCF classes; see ArrayList, LinkedList, and the list goes on.